# Using Oracle stored procedures in MVC ASP.NET with NHibernate 

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

Could you direct me to a sample application which involves using Oracle stored procedures in MVC ASP.NET applications with NHibernate?

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=how+to+use+oracle+stored+procedure+with+nhibernate

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the source for 2.1.1.GA or higher. Open NHibernate.Test project. See /SqlTest/Custom/Oracle/

View the mappings for that test case here

http://nhibernate.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/nhibernate/trunk/nhibernate/src/NHibernate.Test/SqlTest/Custom/Oracle/StoredProcedures.hbm.xml?view=markup

As for ASP.NET MVC, there is nothing about ASP.NET MVC that would make the data access example any different, the key is getting the NH mappings file correct.

Comment: thank u very much u r replay ,
but how to call procedure from model class

thanks for u r valuable help